# How can I fix libstdc++ (or does it need fixing?)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, installation, osx-yosemite

I have been trying to install HEALPix over the last few days on my iMac and I am at something of a dead end as to how to proceed. When I run the necessary make command, I am told that the file `string` does not exist.

```
#  compiling Healpix_cxx/syn_alm_cxx.cc
cd /Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/build.osx/Healpix_cxx && g++  -I/usr/local
/include -I/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/c_utils -I/Users/keir/Software
/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/libfftpack -I/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/libsharp 
-I/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/cxxsupport -I/Users/keir/Software/
Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/Healpix_cxx -I/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/alice 
-I/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/build.osx -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-aliasing=2 
-Wundef -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wredundant-decls -Woverloaded-virtual -Wcast-qual 
-Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wold-style-cast -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors  -g 
-fopenmp -fPIC -O2 -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -ansi -fdata-sections 
-ffunction-sections -c /Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/Healpix_cxx/
syn_alm_cxx.cc
In file included from /Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/Healpix_cxx/
syn_alm_cxx.cc:2:0:
/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/cxxsupport/error_handling.h:35:18: fatal 
error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/build.osx/Healpix_cxx/syn_alm_cxx.o] Error 1
```

I have had a look and it certainly does as is the whole of the libstdc++ library (I think). I have tried many solutions including re-installing Xcode and its Command Line Tools and trying various other versions of gcc (4.8, 4.9, 5.0 and a 4.9 copy from homebrew) - none of which solve the problem.

I have created a test file 'foo.cpp' with just `#include <string>` in it and this will still not compile even if I specify a directory for `string` with the `-I` tag, because it then can't find more headers that `string` depends on. It seems to me that libstdc++ isn't installed in the correct place? Or the '#include' command isn't looking in the right places? Do you have an idea as to how to fix this problem?

Comment: Show the full compiler line which `make` invoked.

Comment: And you say you've tried installing the Xcode command line tools and using `clang` that comes with that?

Comment: @trojanfoe I have edited my post to include the full error (I'm sorry it doesn't fit in the box very well!) I can manually run this command and it will work if I specify `-I/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2` and `-I/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits` (which finds another header that string depends on). However, the full installation is much more than just this initial line. Is there way to more generally fix the location of libstdc++?

Comment: @trojanfoe I have foo.c (and foo.cpp) which are just `#include string` `clang foo.c` throws the error `foo.c:1:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found`

Comment: That's a C file; and `<string>` is C++.

Comment: @trojanfoe `clang foo.cpp` and `clang++ foo.cpp` both give this error:

Comment: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Yeah you need `int main() { return 0; }` in there too.  Slow down a bit; your tests are invalid.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry! OK, I have main as above now and clang and clang++ both work. g++ gives the `file not found` error as above while `gcc foo.c` gives an error about an x86_64 assembler not being installed (which was a problem earlier when trying to install another copy of gcc...)

Comment: Use `clang` and not `gcc`.

Comment: @trojanfoe That is certainly a workaround, though I need OpenMP parallelisation and clang is ignoring the `-fopenmp` argument. The installation gets through all the compilation, before failing with libtool with an error `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd` Ps. It would be good to have a functioning gcc package in any case!